# How to make a view in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have more tables and I want to merge that some table for getting result.....

How can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Views` is just some sort of "stored query". It can be defined as:

```
CREATE VIEW viewname AS SELECT <the rest of select query here>
```

More details at msdn:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214068(SQL.80).aspx

Comment: CREATE VIEW [dbo].[warehouse]
AS
SELECT     dbo.warehouse_master.w_id, dbo.warehouse_master.w_name, dbo.stock.item_name, dbo.stock.stock
FROM         dbo.stock INNER JOIN
                      dbo.warehouse_master ON dbo.stock.w_name = dbo.warehouse_master.w_name

Answer (score 0):

CEATE VIEW.

The rest of teh syntax is in ..... the documentation.

And this question is neither related to C# nor C++. It also does not care what you ate for breakfast. SQL works with strings the server interprets, and the langauge has no matter how the server does that.